# Import html table in Jupyter NB

Tags: python, pandas, import

I couldn't able to read the table from the HTML link

```
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

import pandas as pd 

data = pd.read_html('https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/pub/data/paleo/reconstructions/deboer2014/deboer2014.txt')
```

It has loads of data, anyone faced a similar issue?
link: https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/pub/data/paleo/reconstructions/deboer2014/deboer2014.txt

Gets error -> No tables found

Comment: What did you try beyond this? There's a lot of documentation on the [read_html() method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html). In particular, you'll note at the bottom, 'This function searches for <table> elements and only for <tr> and <th> rows and <td> elements within each <tr> or <th> element in the table. <td> stands for “table data”.' You seem to be pointing the method at a text file and not HTML. You'd want to put the URL in your browser and view the source. You'll see it is text and not HTML. Thus you want a different pandas method to access the data.

Comment: While you are viewing the source of the page, if you're lucky your browswer view will show line numbers. Note the large amount of lines commented out and look into `skiprows` setting in [`pandas.read_table()` method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_table.html).